# neo4j - is there a library for Rest API Transactional

Tags: neo4j

Is there an existing library that I can use that has the functionality:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html

I've looked into https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding , and haven't had luck.  Or maybe I'm missing something.

Any help will be appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the Neo4j JDBC driver that implements the Neo4j 2.0 transactional HTTP endpoint.

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/tree/2.0

The source code for the implementation of the transactional endpoint can be found here:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/blob/95ee4282674af4798a61d2f5c67234e3a5f95b84/src/main/java/org/neo4j/jdbc/rest/TransactionalQueryExecutor.java

Comment: thanks! I'll look into it.  I'm currently using the CypherQueryEngine of the neo4j rest graphdb library but found it a little bit slow.  I'm assuming Transactional HTTP endpoint should be faster, am I on the right track? TIA

Comment: It depends on your scenario. Transactional HTTP endpoint is the way to go in many scenarios requiring batch high read/write throughput. The slowness could be your data model or your Cypher queries need to be optimized.

Comment: Thanks again.  I have an empty db. My query will be as follows: MERGE (a{main:{val1},prop2:{val2}}) MERGE (b{main:{val3}}) CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[r:relationshipname]-(b); 
Currently using batch transaction (per 500) on neo4jgraph rest db. I was getting only like 500 queries per 2 mins. And the 2 mins kept on increasing as well.

Comment: That doesn't sound right in terms of performance. Those queries are not complex. I'd need to know more about your setup to be able to properly diagnose the problem. Feel free to open another SO question with those details and I'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks again.  I've created a separate question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526396/neo4j-batch-insertion-using-neo4j-rest-graph-db

Comment: Are there still no other libraries around that do this? Are there plans to allow the transactional HTTP endpoint to be accessed from Spring Data Neo4j?